# Transfer the contents of 7 textview to another activity at adapter

Tags: android

In my Program use list and adapter .in item_list.xml  have there   textview(cod,time,...) and a picture(editicon). Now, I want when i click on pictur .what's is in cod textview and Other other textview send another activity.How can I send all the contents of the textviews. I just Understand  send the  one contents of a textvie with putextra.Thanks dear friends

public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List contacts;

```
public ContactAdapter(Context context, List< MyContact> contacts) {
    super(context,R.layout.item_list,contacts);


    this.contacts=contacts;



}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyContact contact = contacts.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;


    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.companyname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
        holder.cod = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cod);
        holder.bigan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bign);
        holder.stop = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stop);

        holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.editicon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.fill(contact);
    return convertView;
}


private class ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView companyname;
    public TextView cod;
    public TextView bigan;
    public TextView stop;
    public TextView date;
    public TextView time;


    public TextView price;

    public ImageView editicon;

    public void fill(MyContact contact) {


        companyname.setText(contact.getCompany());

        cod.setText(contact.getCod());
        time.setText(contact.getTime());
        date.setText(contact.getDate());
        bigan.setText(contact.getBigan());
        stop.setText(contact.getStop());
        price.setText(contact.getPrice());
        editicon.setTag(contact.getCod());
       //  editicon.setTag(contact.getBigan());


           editicon.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {





            String codearash = (String) v.getTag();



        Intent intent12 = new Intent(getContext(), Cod.class);

        intent12.putExtra("keycod", codearash);

                   getContext().startActivity(intent12);



        }












    }



}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: post full logcat trace

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing is looking for a `ListView` inside your clicked view, which is `editicon`. This will fail.

You need to fire the intent in your `onClick` implementation in the `ViewHolder` class.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent12 = new Intent(getContext(), Cod.class);
    getContext().startActivity(intent12);
}
```